# Audio file loaded into memory has 500ms delay before playing

Tags: c#, monogame, naudio

In my game, I'm using the tips and code from [this article on fire-and-forget sound with NAudio](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2014/02/fire-and-forget-audio-playback-with.html), using the provided `AudioPlaybackEngine`, `CachedSound`, and `CachedSoundSampleProvider` classes that take an audio file from disc and load its samples into a `float[]` in memory, playing it by mixing it onto an always-playing `MixingSampleProvider`.

Right now, this code is being used to play a jump sound when my test player sprite jumps in the air:

```
private CachedSound jumpSound;
...
jumpSound = new CachedSound(ContentPackageManager.GetAbsoluteFilePath("nsmbwiiJump"));
...
AudioPlaybackEngine.Instance.PlaySound(jumpSound);
```

However, the sound is played after a 500ms or so delay, regardless of whether I play it from disk or from memory - and the delay is the same. What's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you check the file's contents to make sure there aren't 500 ms worth of empty samples at the beginning?

Comment: There was 200 ms of silence on the beginning of the audio - removing it helped, but there's still some delay between the call to `PlaySound` and hearing the sound play.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some latency due to the buffer durations used by `WaveOut` under the hood. Basically you are playing one buffer, while filling another. So you are behind the duration of at least one buffer. NAudio lets you configure the buffer durations and number of buffers before initializing your `WaveOut` device. However, the lower you go, the greater the chance of drop-outs, which will sound like glitches in the audio.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'll test a few different buffer durations/counts to see the sweet spot for short sound effects.

Comment: Setting the delay to 150ms worked pretty well - an almost unnoticeable delay and smooth audio. Thanks!